# Will changing the ProtoBuffer Varint type from a bool type to an enum type representing all bit-mask values be forward compatible?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java, protobuf-c

I want to make the following ProtoBuffer message to be forward compatible.

The current ***Storage*** message defines a ***state*** field as a **bool** type:

```
message Storage {
    bool state = 1;
}
```

In the Protobuffer encoding, it encodes the **Varint** types like the **bool** and the **enum** type in the following format:

```
|1-bit sequence number|4-bit serial number|3-bit data type|n-bit payload|
```

For the **Varint** type, the data type value will become 000:

```
|X|XXXX|000|XXXX...|
```

Since the ***Storage*** message structure only contains one field with a serial number of 1, the sequence number will become 0 as the serial number hasn't been resolved to the last byte. Hence, the above format will become:

```
|0|0001|000|XXXX...|
```

Now, if set ***Storage.state*** = 0, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|<0 will not be encoded>
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8.

if set ***Storage.state*** = 1, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|00000001|
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8 0x1.

Now, I want to change the above ***Storage.state*** definition from the **bool** type to an **enum** type as follows:

```
// BIT7 | BIT6 | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
//-------------------------------------------------------
//  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   | = STATE0 (0)
//  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  1   | = STATE1 (1)
//  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  1   |  0   | = STATE2 (2)
//  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  1   |  1   | = STATE2 (3)
//... so go on
//  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  0   | = STATE2 (254)
//  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   | = STATE2 (255)

enum State {
    STATE0 = 0;
    STATE1 = 1;
    STATE2 = 2;
    STATE3 = 3;
    //... so go on
    STATE254 = 254;
    STATE255 = 255;
}

message Storage {
    State state = 1
}
```

So now, in Protobuf encoding,

if set ***Storage.state*** = State.STATE0, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|<0 will not be encoded>
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8.

if set ***Storage.state*** = State.STATE1, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|00000001|
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8 0x1.

if set ***Storage.state*** = State.STATE2, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|00000010|
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8 0x2.

if set ***Storage.state*** = State.STATE255, it will be stored as follows:

```
|0|0001|000|11111111|
```

The Protobuffer value for the ***Storage*** message will become 0x8 0xFF.

Will this change still be forward compatible for **proto2** and **proto3** and in C and Java?

I based my question on the reference below:
[google protocol buffer -- the coding principle of protobuf II](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/google-protocol-buffer-the-coding-principle-of-protobuf-ii.html)

Comment: question: your state - are those 256 options all separate things, or are you actually trying to represent bitwise state values, i.e. a `[Flags] enum` in C# terms (yes, I know you didn't ask about C#)

Comment: Yes, bitwise state values but specifically for C and Java implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you're actually trying to store here is: the bitwise state values - what might be a `[Flags] enum` in C# (mentioned purely to set context).

Honestly, declaring an enum with a value per bit combination: isn't a good idea; it will escalate very quickly, and it isn't intuitive to use. It also leaves potential for silly errors when copy/pasting large volumes of lines...

```proto
// omitted... 212 lines - but would you spot the error?
STATE213 = 213;
STATE214 = 214;
STATE215 = 214;
STATE216 = 216;
STATE217 = 217;
// ... etc
```

(OK, that specific error requires the allow-alias flag, but: you get the point)

---

In proto2, enums are expected to be recognised; when unexpected enum values are encountered, it gets a bit... hazy, with any of:

1. parse failure
2. treated as an unknown field (needing to be accessed via a separate API)
3. silently handled and parsed via the integer value (which has the effect of preserving bit flags)

Since every flag combination will not have an enum definition, what you *want* here is option 3, but that isn't guaranteed in all implementations.

---

In proto3, the framework leans as far in the direction of 3 as possible, [explicitly in the language specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum), with the integer value being stored and retrieved (which has the effect of preserving bit flags) **but** it is also explicitly called out that some platforms *do not allow open enums types* - for example, Java.

---

Because of this limitation, since you mention [java](/questions/tagged/java) in the tags, I would recommend simply using an integer directly. It will at least work similarly on all implementations. By comparison to your proposed solution, it is *at least as usable* - but usually a lot *more* usable; consider how it works as an enum:

```
obj.state = State.State217;
```

vs as an integer:

```
obj.state = 217;
```

This will also allow bitwise combination/test/etc operations to be used re values, which isn't the case for closed enum types.

---

As for whether `bool`, `enum` and `int32`/`uint32`/`sint32` (and the 64-bit counterparts) are technically interchangeable (scale permitting): yes; they're all encoded as varint.

Comment: Yes, I prefer option 3 because I already have an embedded ANSI C structure that is converted into embedded NanoPB C proto2 payload and sent to my Android app via USB/Bluetooth serial interface, which uses the Java proto2 ProtoBuf format. Due to a lack of foresight in the C structure design, the state field was defined as an 8-bit integer to represent a boolean state. As a result, I'd like to switch the state field's ProtoBuf definition from an 8-bit payload data Varint bool type to a Varint enum type with all possible 8-bit bitmask value definitions.

Comment: Since there is no int8 in ProtoBuf and using the bytes definition for a single byte is overkill, that's my only option. Unless you want to give your opinion on this.

Comment: @ecle it will take the same space as an int32 vs an enum, specifically: 1 byte if the MSB isn't set, and 2 bytes if it is; so: what are you gaining via the enum? I can't see a single thing that this gives you. As for the `bytes` type: yes, unnecessary overhead here, don't do that. If the enum part is to validate the defined values (i.e. disallow 3624): that won't work reliably. That isn't what enums are for.

Comment: Marc, I really appreciate it. Option 3 is now implemented (using the Varint enum type) on the Android app side, but nothing has changed on the embedded C side (maintains the Varint bool type). So far, everything has gone smoothly. To pass the integer value to assign the enum value, Android generates the 'Package.State.forNumber(int)' ProtoBuf method. In response to the suggestion that the enum field be assigned an integer value instead of an enum value, I can use the method to perform a bitwise mask integer operation.

Comment: Instead of the original boolean definition, I could change the embedded C code later to define more state options for future build releases while remaining compatible with the current build.

Comment: @ecle ". In response to the suggestion that the enum field be assigned an integer value instead of an enum value, I can use the method to perform a bitwise mask integer operation." - you can do that with an integer value, too :) Genuine question: what is the enum giving you here? I literally can't think of a single benefit, but I'm happy to learn

Comment: The active state of the Frequency Hopping (FHOP) scanning function was previously maintained by the boolean state. But now, in the future build, my FHOP designer decides to use a bitmask method with the enum type for the state to define three different levels of frequency spacing. As a result, we can now set the following values: bit 0 for active (the current build), bit 2 and bit 1 for the spacing bit mask (future builds).

Comment: @ecle but proto doesn't have a concept of flags enums, so instead of declaring an enum value per bit, you'd be declaring 2^N enum values for N bits - which is... pointless; that's called "an integer"

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point... It is just that I want to maintain the same 2 bytes protobuf length achieved by storing the Varint bool and the Varint enum type between the old and future builds when the value > 0 and 1 byte protobuf length when the value = 0, so that it is compatible the 8-bit field in the embedded C structure.

Comment: @ecle and for the Nth time: literally nothing changes in the payload between an int32 and an enum; they are encoded *identically*, so: in terms of bytes, anything you say about an enum: applies identically to an int32

Comment: Oh, okay, I assumed that when the int32 data type is used, it means that a 4-byte integer for the data payload is automatically stored after the protobuf type definition byte. However, it appears that it now depends on the data payload value: if the value is 0xFF, the data payload is one byte; if the value is 0xFFFF, the payload is two bytes, and so on.

Comment: @ecle what you said applies to `fixed32`, however: `int32` is stored as a varint (oh, and 0xFF would be 2 bytes, 0xFFFF would be 3 bytes; varint is basically "7 bits plus continuation", so 0x7F is the largest value that fits in 1 byte, and 0x3FFF is the largest value that fits in 2 bytes)